# React hooks to toogle class in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle

I know similar questions have been asked in the past but I think none of them hit the mark. Most are based on class components and are not exactly the same as what I am trying to do.
So I have two components that I want to toggle on and off by onClick.

```
      <div
        className={`${showInfo === false ? "carousel_wrapper" : "no_display"}`}
      ></div>

      {/* <!-- page info below --> */}

      <div
        className={`${showInfo === true ? "page_info_content" : "no_display"}`}
      >
```

I have the var set to true by default:

```
var showInfo = true;
```

And now I am trying to toggle the class by the click. I understand that in order for this to work in the function component I need to have useState as this is the way React watches changes in the elements.
But can I use "useState" to change the default value? Like this:

```
let toggleInfo = () => {
  const [infTrue, infoFalse] = useState(true);
  showInfo = infoFalse(false);
  return showInfo; 
  };
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Or does this make no sense at all? Please note I am quite new to React and JS in general so I may be looking at this from a strange angle but it seems strange that JS E6+ has a simple toggle option yet an advanced tool like React requires a much more complex approach. I am sure this feeling will change with time. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried watching any React basic tutorials on Youtube? This is wrong on so many levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the state variable outside the function toggleInfo.

Your functional component should look something like this

```
const funcComp = ()=>{
  const [infTrue, infoFalse] = useState(true);
  const toggleInfo = () => {
       infoFalse(false);
       }
  return(
   <>
   <button onClick={toggleInfo}>Click to toggle </button>
     <div
        className={`${showInfo === false ? "carousel_wrapper" : "no_display"}`}
      ></div>

      {/* <!-- page info below --> */}

      <div
        className={`${showInfo === true ? "page_info_content" : "no_display"}`}
      >
    </>
 )

}
```

Welcome to React and JS. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! I did something not quite like this but similar. Your reply helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

React hooks must be a the root level of your component. It cannot be inside anything else. Once you declare the state you can change it by using the method declared in the index 1 of the array :

```
const MyComponent = () => {
 const [state, setState] = useState(false)
 
 return <button onClick={() => setState(true)} >Click Me</button>
}
```

Everytime the state is changed, the component will rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Define the state in the function body. Rules of hooks say they can *only* be called from the functional component body or in other hooks. The `useState` hook returns an array of state and state update function, i.e. `const [state, setState] = useState();`.

```
const [infoTrue, setInfoTrue] = useState(true);
```

Then call state updater in callback with the next value, i.e. `false`.

```
const toggleInfo = () => setInfoTrue(false);
```

Set class. Since `infoTrue` is a boolean value, use its truthy/falsey to your advantage, i.e. don't compare against `true` or `false` directly. Also, the string template is unnecessary, just conditionally return the classname string.

```
<div
  className={infoTrue ? "page_info_content" : "no_display"}
>
```